# Ajax chat system - use query to select twice from a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I am trying to build an ajax chat system. Basically I have 2 tables, the `users` table and the  `pm` (private messaging) table. I am joining these tables.

How can I get all the information from the users table for person 1, and person 2 (receiver and sender) in one query so I can order all the chats by the correct time?

I tried using the normal join to get this done, but I have realised that it sends only one set of data from the users table. Is it possible to join the same table twice?

I have tried this:

```
SELECT pm.id, pm.message, pm.reciever, pm.sender, pm.senttime, pm.rread, 
u.username, u.name, u.surname, u.fullname, u.profile, u2.username, u2.name, 
u2.surname, u2.fullname, u2.profile 
FROM pm, users u, users u2
WHERE (pm.reciever = 1 AND pm.sender = 2) OR (pm.reciever = 2 AND pm.sender = 1)
```

But it is returning multiples.

Comment: Can you explain more about your chat system? Is it a chat between two users, or a general chat? How is `pm` table linked to users?

Comment: Are you using a while loop to display the messages?? I'm confused as to what you are doing, as for returning the correct time, give each new entry a unique ID that auto increments with each new entry, then ORDER BY id ASC

Comment: I am using PDO to get the results, then using a foreach to get the information into XML so I can load via AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to compare your ids from the different tables:

```
SELECT pm.id, pm.message, pm.reciever, pm.sender, pm.senttime, pm.rread, s.username, s.name, s.surname, s.fullname, s.profile, r.username, r.name, r.surname, r.fullname, r.profile 
FROM pm, users s, users r
WHERE (r.id = pm.reciever) AND (s.id = pm.sender) AND ((r.id = 1 AND s.id = 2) OR (r.id = 2 AND s.id = 1))
```